# get metrics from influxdb internal database

Tags: monitoring, influxdb

I need to monitor requests to influxdb by databases to understand which of there is most active. I'm trying to get data from _internal database, but there is no explanations of keys,tags and so on.

Comment: Couple of link:
https://www.influxdata.com/blog/how-to-use-the-show-stats-command-and-the-_internal-database-to-monitor-influxdb/ |
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/administration/server_monitoring/ |
https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/blob/master/monitor/README.md |
https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/

Comment: Thank's, that was usefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [ticket](https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/pull/777) about documenting of internal stats, was closed with desicion

> to not document the *_internal* database

So there is no any full documentation about it, only a bits of information on Internet.
Thank's a lot for your comment's.

Answer (score 0):

You could check Chronograf. All measurements, tags and fields  of _internal are listed there.

Or you have a look at https://github.com/influxdata/docs.influxdata.com/pull/777.
There was an attempt to document _internal.

Comment: Thank you, i'm already using Chronograf, but i'm looking for detailed definition of data, stored in _internal, f.ex. size of databases today, yestarday and so on. I need it, beacuse I can't understand who create such chart.